# Adding quotation makes to JSON String which contains some XML values

Tags: javascript, json, regex, xml

I'm trying to format a JSON input string in Javascript so that I can use it as a map.

```
{accountNumber:E22E6178D16777E1E053020011AC64B0,paymentMethodObject:<ns2:Token>123</ns2:Token><ns2:Type>CreditCard</ns2:Type>,preview:true}
```

To do this I need to put quotation marks around each key and value. Like here:

```
{
    "accountNumber": "12345",
    "paymentMethodObject": "<ns2:Token>123</ns2:Token><ns2:Type>CreditCard</ns2:Type>",
    "preview": "true"
}
```

The problem is when I try to do it, quotes get added to the XML values also because they also contain a colon.

Comment: how do you get your original input string?

Comment: It's a response from an API call.

Comment: if it's a response from an API call, it should return you the string in the format you expect by default.. If it is not, then that's the problem with the API provider..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to use method `replace` with pattern [Regex](https://jex.im/regulex/#!embed=true&flags=&re=(%5Cw%2B)%3A(%5B%5C%2F%3C%3E%3A%5Cw%2B%5D%2B)) that match `key:value` replace it with surrounded by quotes pair!

```js
let strJSON = '{accountNumber:E22E6178D16777E1E053020011AC64B0,paymentMethodObject:<ns2:Token>123</ns2:Token><ns2:Type>CreditCard</ns2:Type>,preview:true}';
let objJSON = strJSON.replace(/(\w+):([\/<>:\w+]+)/g,'"$1":"$2"');
console.log(objJSON)
```